# Is there an existing library or set of scripts to write recurring event strings for the Google Calendar API in Python?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, icalendar, rfc2445

I have a Python-based program that adds events to a Google Calendar. To add events that repeat, I need to specify a recurrent_data string that conforms to the RFC 2445 standard. An example is below, from http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#CreatingRecurring:

```
'DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20070501\r\n'
        + 'DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20070502\r\n'
        + 'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=Tu;UNTIL=20070904\r\n'
```

Has anyone written a set of functions that will automatically generate these strings, and/or otherwise write recurring events to Google Calendar? It doesn't seem too difficult to write some functions myself, but I wanted to check whether I'd be duplicating any long-standing efforts in the ical or GData API communities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I found was the [iCalendar module](http://codespeak.net/icalendar/) which can create RFC 2445-compliant data. Your best bet right now might be creating a template based on the [Example](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/1.0/elements.html#gdRecurrence) section here provided by Google.

Answer (score 0):

There is another library called [icalendar](https://github.com/marook/icalendar) which is available as node.js npm module called [icalendar](http://search.npmjs.org/#/icalendar).